# PHP/MYSQL Two table linked with a third

Tags: php, mysql

New in PHP and mysql, I have been blocking a problem for a few days now.
I have a table "personnes" in which this find the info of my users (id, nom, prenom...) and a table projets which contains the info of my projects (id, nom, description...).

I also have a third table `projetspersonnes (id, id_projet, id_personne)`.

I am looking for a way to connect one or more people to one or more projects.

I have searched the internet, but I have nothing corresponding to my problem.

I tried several solutions (including one that linked me absolutely all my people to all my projects), but I unfortunately did not find the solution.

This is why I turn to you for help.

Here is my view PHP code:

```
<form action=<?php echo $formActionUrl ?> method=POST>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Choisissez la ou les personnes à ajouter</td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($personnes as $pers) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $pers["nom"] . " " . $pers["prenom"] ?></td>
            <td> <input type='checkbox' name='idPers<?php echo $pers["id"]?>' value="<?php echo $pers["id"]?>"> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Choisissez le ou les projets à ajouter</td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($projets as $proj) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $proj["nom"]?></td>
            <td> <input type='checkbox' name='idProj<?php echo $proj["id"]?>' value="<?php echo $proj["id"]?>"> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=submit name="action" value=<?php echo $btnActionValue; ?>></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

And here my actual model PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "add") {
    $req = "INSERT INTO projetspersonnes SELECT projets.id, personnes.id FROM projets, personnes WHERE projets.id = :projets.id, personnes.id = :personnes.id;)";
    $stm = $sqlQuery->prepare($req);
    $postValue = $_POST;
    unset($postValue["action"]);
    $stm->execute($postValue);

    header("location: projets_personnes.php?add=true");
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You want to link three tables?

Comment: @JayBlanchard ??? why? moreover WHERE is used in SELECT, not in INSERT.

Comment: Well @Akina for one thing, WHERE with multiple clauses require `AND` or `OR`. They've used a comma to separate the 2 clauses which isn't correct syntax.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That's true, a comma is syntax error.

Comment: Because an INSERT does not have to meet any conditions @Akina

Comment: @JayBlanchard Not INSERT at all but INSERT .. VALUES only (and its variation INSERT .. SET). Whereas OP uses INSERT .. SELECT.

Comment: Ah, I totes missed dat @Akina

Comment: can you please share the table structure with some sample data and the desired output format as well?

Comment: @JayBlanchard i want link table "personnes" and "projets" in the third table "projetspersonnes".

Comment: @Akina, i test too INSERT VALUE, but that not work work (the command I tested, but it didn't have to be the right one)

Comment: @NikhilGyan just need to link one or more people to one or more projects. If i need tu use information, i need first name and last name of personnes and name of projets

Comment: What do you mean by "link"? What exactly is not working with all the given code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is to change your checkbox name, all your chackbox have a unique name so it's difficult to get the selected,

```
// for the user :
<input type='checkbox' name='idPers[]' value="<?php echo $pers["id"]?>">

// for the project :
<input type='checkbox' name='idProj[]' value="<?php echo $proj["id"]?>">
```

and the code for your model :

```
if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "add") {
    foreach($_POST['idPers'] as $idPers){
        foreach($_POST['idProj'] as $idProj){
            $req = "INSERT INTO projetspersonnes SET id_projet = :idProj, id_personne = :idPers";
            $stm = $sqlQuery->prepare($req);
            $stm->bindValue(':idProj', $idProj, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->bindValue(':idPers', $idPers, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->execute();
        }
    }
    header("location: projets_personnes.php?add=true");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
It just misses a little ; at the end of the sql request, but that's it.
Thank you

Comment: Nice, i just correct the answer. dont forget to validate it if all is ok for you